# What purpose does the dot( . ) fulfil in this piece of code

Tags: c++

In an example that's in my C++ book, I've found this piece of code at the end of an example problem, which verified if 3 integers were in an arithmetic progression.

`if (b==(a+c)/2.)`

I don't think I've seen the dot after 2 ever used in such a way and I don't know what it's purpose is here.

Comment: When you write `2.` in your mathematics class, what does it mean?

Comment: Now, let us imagine, for a moment, that there was a `0` after that `.`...

Comment: As to your book, it is not a good thing that a book has this.  Why?  Because it would be difficult to tell if that is actually a `.`, a speck of dirt, or some tiny insect squashed in-between the pages.  That's why adding `.0` is (and should be) done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no one writes `2.` or `.2` in math. I've only ever see that in American English

Comment: `no one` -- There are 8 billion people in the world.  I am sure that someone has written this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I said "in math". It's not a valid notation in proper math. In proper writing most languages require both the integer and the fractional part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2.` is a double literal. It's the same as `2.0`.

Integer division is different than floating point division, so in some cases having a double instead of an int makes an important difference.

---

Although this form is perfectly valid, for readability purposes often `2.0` is preferred. In some (not all) newer languages derived from C++ like C# it is not allowed, i.e. you are forced to write `2.0`.